# Trying to arrange text in a HTML5/CSS3 footer block

Tags: html, footer

I am new to HTML5 and CSS3, and am working on a project for a beginning HTML5 class I'm taking and can't find an answer to my problem. I am stuck on how to best format the text I want to put into my page footer. I need two columns with the first column being about 2/3 of the width of the footer, and the second being about 1/3 of the width.

---

```
               This is the first line                       This is the first
```

### This is the test for the second line of the foo       This is the second line

Should I use some type of Div tags, or can I make the second column using an Aside? Or, should I use a table? I think I understand how to make the footer block in CSS, but don't know the best way to format the text into two different sized columns. Any advice I can get would really be appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use div tags:

```
<style>
#left, #right{
    float: left;
}
#left {
    width: 66%;
}
#right {
    width: 33%;
}
</style>
<div id="left">
    <p>Left Content</p>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <p>Right Content</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div><!--Clears the float-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted above which you can use but as I've already done this so here it is, same approach so I hope it helps you:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-col">This is a column</div>
    <div id="right-col">This is a column</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{ width: 600px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; border: solid 1px red; padding: 1px; }
#left-col{ float: left; width: 66%; border: solid 1px blue; }
#right-col{ float: right; width: 33%; border: solid 1px green; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uKrsM/ I added borders to show the width

Answer (score 0):

Using percentage widths is probably the easiest way, although I would recommend taking a look at Bootstrap or a similar framework for layouts.

Here is bootstrap: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ 
And this initializr tool is good for getting a new project up and running quickly: http://www.initializr.com/

For the purpose of learning how it works - try using a percentage width example like the one below:

http://jsfiddle.net/tsdexter/nnfLD/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
<header><h1>This is a header</h1></header>
<section id="content">This is some content</section>
<footer>
    <div class="twothirds">
        This is two thirds
    </div>
    <div class="onethird">
        This is one third
    </div>
    <div class="clear-fix"></div>
</footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.twothirds {
    width: 64.66666%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
}
.onethird {
    width: 33.33333%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
}
.clear-fix {clear: both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use some type of Div tags, or can I make the second column using an Aside? Or, should I use a table?

If the content of the 2 columns is related or part of the same context then use div for your layout. Using an *aside* tag would be semantically incorrect. Percentage divs for this type of layout is probably the best solution

> ...don't know the best way to format the text into two different sized columns.

I don't think i understand exactly what you mean here. The text will wrap itself in its containing element (the div). Use proper hierarchy for your content -- h1/h2 tags followed by paragraph or lists, and/or HTML5 tags such as *section/article* -- but that really depends on your content. As far as styling goes you can always use css classes for styling exactly the portion of text you wish. (headings, paragraphs or lists or spans...etc)